# How to structure a form that needs to validate one to many relationships nested on 2 levels?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have 3 models, that I want to manage from a single page.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...

class Model2(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    ...

class Model3(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Model2)
    ...
```

Say I'm on the html page that edits `Model1` instances, and I'm editing instance with id 1 if Model1

I'd like here to also edit all the `Model2` instances whose parent is the current `Model1` instances. More explicitly I'd like to edit the current `Model2` instances, add new ones, and even delete existing ones.

Also, I'd like to be able to edit/ add/ delete new instances of `Model3` related to instances of `Model2` that I'd see on this page.

My question does not regard the templates. I'll be fine with those, as soon as I get my forms validating what they are supposed to be validating.

**IDEA1**
What I thought about doing so far was to hack `Form` and `FormSet` objects, but when I looked inside the formset for instance, it really seems it wasn't made to support this kind of deeply connected relationships.

**IDEA2**
I also thought about having an html form with the input elements generated dynamically, with names that would describe this complex hierarchy, and then preprocessing this data before passing it for validation to simpler forms.

So I'm talking about something like

```
data = {
  'model1_name': 'Joe',
  'model1_1_model2_color': 'red',
  'model1_1_model2_1_model3_province': 'Florence',
  'model1_1_model2_2_model3_province': 'Lombardia',
  'model1_2_model2_color': 'blue',
  'model1_2_model2_1_model3_accepted': True
}
```

See how I basically generated this relationship graph

```
model1 (name=Joe)
 \-> model2 (color=red)
 |     \-> model3 (province=Florence)
 |     \-> model3 (province=Lombardia)
 \-> model2 (color=blue)
       \-> model3 (accepted=True)
```

So far this second idea looks more manageable to me however I'd have to use Javascript to generate the form element names.

Anyway I'd really like to know if someone else has attempted to do this, what solution worked.

Comment: what i do in this case is two things, one on client-side form and one on server-side. On client-side i have dependent-selects which when updated can fetch new data based on the selected values (this can be another dependent model) and construct  part of the form with these model data (with appropriate keys). Then on submit have the server-side validate al these and check relationships

Comment: btw i'm using a custom client-side MVVM framework for this, which includes model construction and validation from declarative form fields and so on.. i have a similar validation framework on server-side